# Can you have a break in T-SQL Case statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Is there a way in T-SQL to have a case statement to review logic and if a row meets criteria then it won't evaluate that row for the remainder of the `case` statements. (like a break in C++)

For example:

```
Case When X is true Then scenario A
Case when Y is true Then scenario B
Case when Z is true Then scenario C
```

row 1 - if scenario A is true (but it could also be scenario B) what I want to happen is that for row one we mark row A, and skip evaluating the rest cases. Then we move on to Row 2 etc.

-- I should add the case statement is for an update -- and here is a sample of the data.

```
set [fixed_brand_new] =     
CASE WHEN   ((CustCount = 1 AND src.order_fix_or_flex = 'fx'))                                          
    OR                                                                                                                                                                          
    (CustCount > 2 AND src.order_fx_or_fl = 'fx' AND GapDiff2 is NULL)                   
    OR 
    (CustCount = 2 AND src.order_fx_or_fl  = 'fx' AND season_counter = MaxSeasonCounter AND GapDiff2 is NULL  )
THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END,

    [flex_brand_new] =          
CASE WHEN   ((CustCount = 1 AND src.order_fx_or_fl  = 'fl'))                                    
    OR
    (CustCount > 2 AND src.order_fx_or_fl  = 'fl'  AND GapDiff2 is NULL)                         
     OR 
    (CustCount = 2 AND src.order_fx_or_fl  = 'fl' AND src.season_counter = MaxSeasonCounter AND GapDiff2 is NULL  )                         
THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statements, when evaluating multiple columns together, first WHEN to evaluate as TRUE is returned.  This example should demonstrate how that works:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [X] BIT
      , [Y] BIT
      , [Z] BIT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [X]
                        , [Y]
                        , [Z]
                      )
VALUES ( 1, 1, 0 )
     , ( 0, 1, 1 )
     , ( 0, 1, 0 )
     , ( 0, 0, 1 );

SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN [X] = 1 THEN 'Scenario: A x=1 others don''t matter'
            WHEN [Y] = 1 THEN 'Scenario: B x=0 and y=1, what Z is doesn''t matter'
            WHEN [Z] = 1 THEN 'Scenario: C x=0 and y=0 and z=1'
       END EvaluateTogether
     , CASE WHEN [X] = 1 THEN 'Scenario A'
       END --Evalute each individual column as another column
     , CASE WHEN [Y] = 1 THEN 'Scenario B'
       END --Evalute each individual column as another column
     , CASE WHEN [Z] = 1 THEN 'Scenario C'
       END --Evalute each individual column as another column
FROM   @TestData;
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand the explanation -- I added an example above with a statement of what my update looks like. Are you saying if i remove the 'END' from each statement i could still have an working update to evaluate each line?

Comment: without including END in each statement (without separating out each statement SQL throws an error)

Comment: @Elizabeth in that situation no. You're updating 2 different columns fixed_brand_new and flex_brand_new which means you'll have to keep the 2 separate case statements.

Comment: @Elizabeth if you're trying to minimize or simply that update statement.  You could potentially look at moving a lot of that into the where clause, what's duplicated across the 2 and then just have the evaluation of order_fix_or_flex as 'fl' or 'fx' on each of those fields.

Comment: Thank you, i was just showing a sample of my update (I have about 10 possible update scenarios and a lot of variations of data). That is my issue. I need to figure out a way to accurately pull each case but i would like to not look at the following statements once a correct scenario has been found.